# Connect Blackberry Simulator to BES(Enterprise Server)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to replicate a scenario where user's will be able to view the PDF files onto the blackberry browser(in the absence of any PDF viewer). Some of the users on our production site are not able to view pdf inside the browser. They are receiving an error "unknown media type:application/pdf", while in case of some pdf's its working fine.

I was not able to replicate the above mentioned scenario using an MDS alone, as it never rendered the pdf inside the browser.

Anyone has a better solution to test such scenarios or if you could list down the steps to connect a Blackberry Simulator to BES where I could test this?